# Logging entities change using SessionInterceptor in orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I wanted to log changes of certain entities (marked with attribute) so, I created `AbstractSessionInterceptor`'s descendant to get access to entity changes. Also I want to know who did this changes, so I need to access current user, so through `IWorkContextAccessor` I'm creating `IWorkContextScope`, getting `WorkContext` and trying to get user, when existing entity is being edited I'm able to access current user, when new entity is created with contentmanager I'm getting timeout exception.. Then I getting `WorkContext` via `IWorkContextAccessor.GetContext()` I'm get infinite loop (interceptor is being called again and again). Any Ideas and suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Source:

```
public class AccountInterceptor : AbstractSessionInterceptor
{
    private IProtocolLogger _logger;
    private readonly Type _mainAttrType = typeof(ProtocolAttribute);
    private readonly Type _fieldAttrType = typeof(ProtocolFieldAttribute);
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    ISessionFactoryHolder _sessionFactoryHolder;

    public AccountInterceptor(IWorkContextAccessor contextAccessor, ISessionFactoryHolder sessionFactoryHolder)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _sessionFactoryHolder = sessionFactoryHolder;
    }

    public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, NHibernate.Type.IType[] types)
    {
        var t = entity.GetType();
        var attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(_mainAttrType, true);

        if (attributes.Length != 0)
        {
            IWorkContextScope scope = _contextAccessor.CreateWorkContextScope();

            WorkContext context = scope.WorkContext;

            if (context != null)
            {
                var attr = (ProtocolAttribute)attributes.FirstOrDefault();
                var currentDic = currentState.Select((s, i) => new { S = s, Index = i }).ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.S);

                var prvDic = previousState.Select((s, i) => new { S = s, Index = i }).ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.S);

                var diff = compare(currentDic, prvDic);

                if (!attr.LogAllData)
                {
                    List<string> properties = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var propety in t.GetProperties())
                    {
                        var propertyAttributes = propety.GetCustomAttributes(_fieldAttrType, true);
                        if (propertyAttributes.Length != 0)
                            properties.Add(propety.Name);
                    }
                    if (properties.Count != 0)
                    {
                        var necesseryProps = propertyNames.Select((s, i) => new { S = s, Index = i }).Where(p => properties.Contains(p.S)).ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.S);
                        TupleList<int, object, object> ToRemove = new TupleList<int, object, object>();
                        foreach (var tuple in diff)
                        {
                            if (!necesseryProps.Keys.Contains(tuple.Item1))
                            {
                                ToRemove.Add(tuple);
                            }
                        }
                        ToRemove.ForEach(d => diff.Remove(d));
                    }
                }

                if (diff.Count != 0)
                {
                    _logger = ProtocolLogger.GetInstance();
                    var sessionFactory = _sessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory();
                    var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

                    var user = GetCurrentUser(session, context.HttpContext);

                    string propertiesFormat = GetPropertiesStringFormat(diff, propertyNames);
                    object[] param = new object[] { DateTime.Now, entity, propertyNames };

                    string entityId = string.Empty;
                    try
                    {
                        if (entity is IAuditable)
                        {
                            entityId = ((IAuditable)entity).Id.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        entityId = entity.ToString();
                    }
                    foreach (var pair in diff)
                    {
                        ProtocolPropertyInfo info = new ProtocolPropertyInfo(propertyNames[pair.Item1], Convert.ToString(pair.Item2), Convert.ToString(pair.Item3));

                        _logger.Log(user, entity, entityId, session, context, Operation.Write, info);
                    }

                    session.Flush();
                    session.Close();
                }

            }
        }

        return base.OnFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
    }

    private object GetCurrentUser(ISession session, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null || !httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated || !(httpContext.User.Identity is FormsIdentity))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var formsIdentity = (FormsIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity;
        var userData = formsIdentity.Ticket.UserData ?? "";

        // the cookie user data is {userId};{tenant}
        var userDataSegments = userData.Split(';');

        if (userDataSegments.Length != 2)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var userDataId = userDataSegments[0];
        var userDataTenant = userDataSegments[1];

        int userId;
        if (!int.TryParse(userDataId, out userId))
        {
            return null;
        }

        Type regType = Assembly.Load("Orchard.Users").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "UserPartRecord");
        var user = session.Get(regType, userId);

        return user;
    }

    private string GetPropertiesStringFormat(TupleList<int, object, object> diffDic, string[] propertyNames)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var pair in diffDic)
        {
            result.AppendFormat("Property name {0}, New value {1}, Old value {2}", propertyNames[pair.Item1], pair.Item2, pair.Item3);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    private TupleList<int, object, object> compare(Dictionary<int, object> dic1, Dictionary<int, object> dic2)
    {
        var diff = new TupleList<int, object, object>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> pair in dic1)
        {
            if (!Equals(pair.Value, dic2[pair.Key]))
            {
                diff.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value, dic2[pair.Key]);
            }
        }

        return diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the new audit trail feature?

Answer (score 0):

*Never* ever start new work context inside your interceptor - infinite loop is guaranteed. And in fact, you don't have to. Each interceptor is already *instantiated per work context*, so you can inject dependencies via ctor, as usual.

To access current user you can either:

- inject `IOrchardServices` and use `.WorkContext.CurrentUser` property, or
- or use `contextAccessor.GetContext()` to get context and then call `CurrentUser` on it.

Also, be careful with performing database operations from inside the interceptor as those will most likely result in infinite loops and throw stack overflow exceptions.

Comment: thanks, but in fact I'll get circular dependency if inject IOrchardServices, and using contextAccessor.GetContext(), when new item is created by contentmanager is actually causing infinite loop... I decided to listen to Bertrand Le Roy's advice and modify AuditTrail module for my requirements.

Comment: Could you please file a bug about that? It should not happen.

Comment: I've created a bug report.

Comment: I am running version 1.8.1 and it seems that I can not inject IOrchardServices however I do not have any issues using contextAccessor.GetContext(). (No infinite loops)